# cross compiling e2fsprogs for arm

Tags: android, compilation, arm, libraries

I'm trying to cross compile extundelete linux package for arm. I want to run it in my Android device.

When I try to run `./configure` it says `Can't find ext2fs library`. I've found the problem is extundelete requires ext2fs library. This library is into e2fsprogs package.

So I've tried to cross compile e2fsprogs. Static compilation is not posible because it seems e2fsprogrs needs `--enable-elf-shlibs` to run make command correctly. I've built e2fsprogrs with command:

```
"./configure --host=arm-none-linux-gnueabi" CC=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc --enable-elf-shlibs && make && make install && make install-libs.
```

It runs correctly and I get cross compiled e2fsprogs. Problem is this is getting libraries compiled dinamically and I dont how to pass it to extundelete cross compilation and then what archives I have to copy to my android device.

I think it's posible to need to link the .so .a files I'm getting in e2fsprogs cross compilation but I dont understand exactly how to make this.

In one of my adventures cross compiling extundelete I got binary arm extundelete file but this was compiled dynamically linked and uses shared libraries. I tried to copy extundelete binary and .so files from e2fsprogs to my Android device but it doesnt run correctly.

Anyone can help me to understand the wonderful world of dynamic cross compilation?

Answer (score 1):

../configure --host=arm-none-linux-gnueabi --with-cc=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc --with-linker=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ld --with-ldopts=--static --prefix=/tmp/target

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that newer version (1.43 for example) doesn't use --with-cc or --with-ldopts anymore. --with-linker also isn't used any more.

Use CC= and LDFLAGS= instead.
example:

```
./configure --host=arm-none-linux-gnueabi CC=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc LDFLAGS=--static --prefox=/target/dirctory
```

Cheers!